# How to configure sonar properties for C++ project

Tags: c++, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to generate sonar report for C++ project. But I am getting "Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property" error. I am using SonarQube Data Center EditionVersion 7.9.4 (build 35981). PFB properties that i am having in pom.xml.

```
<sonar.maven.version>3.6.0.1398</sonar.maven.version>
<sonar.scm.enabled>true</sonar.scm.enabled>
<sonar.sources>.</sonar.sources>
<sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output>build_wrapper_output_directory</sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output>
<sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
```

I tried by giving c++, C++ in <sonar.language>c++</sonar.language>.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was fixed by adding:

```
-Dsonar.language=cxx
-Dsonar.inclusions=**/*.cxx,**/*.cpp,**/*.cc,**/*.c,**/*.hxx,**/*.hpp,**/*.hh,**/*.h,**/*.r
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.java
-Dsonar.cxx.file.suffixes=.cxx,.cpp,.cc,.c,.hxx,.hpp,.hh,.h,.r
```

You'll need to remove the "D" and adapt this to XML tags (and all might not be necessary) but it may fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Julien BERNARD. After adding above configurations in pom.xml, getting below exception.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project Core: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper-dump.json.
I have downloaded build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip. I am not sure where to put. Kindly advice

Comment: Hello @Sangeetharaj, I'm sorry, but I don't know =/ I haven't encountered that error before and it doesn't ring a bell

Answer (score 0):

Need to download the Build Wrapper directly from your SonarQube server, so that its version perfectly matches your version of the plugin.

http://localhost:9000/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip

http://localhost:9000/static/cpp/build-wrapper-macosx-x86.zip

http://localhost:9000/static/cpp/build-wrapper-win-x86.zip

Based on operating system extract respective zip file and place files into your project root directory. Use below code to run clean all. It will generate build-wrapper-dump.json and build-wrapper.log files. You can find them in output directory.

```
<execution>
    <id>mfas-core-build-wrapper</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <executable>build-wrapper-linux-x86-64</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--out-dir</argument>
            <argument>${output}</argument>
            <argument>make</argument>
            <argument>clean</argument>
            <argument>all</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Need to add below properties in pom.xml

```
<sonar.language>cxx</sonar.language>
<sonar.sources>.</sonar.sources>
<sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
<sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output>${output}</sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output>
<sonar.inclusions>**/*.c,**/*.h,**/*.xml</sonar.inclusions>
<sonar.exclusions>**/*.java</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.cxx.file.suffixes>.c,.h</sonar.cxx.file.suffixes>
```

Now run sonar scanner to analysis and generate the report.